# Accessing Eclipse C/C++ Build Info Through API

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Are there APIs for an Eclipse plug-in to get C/C++ build information for a project?
[image: Build Information]

I've gone through the Eclipse CDT Plug-in Developer Guide but haven't been able to find anything that would help me get this information for a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is in the guide. The sections you need are:

- [Managed Build Extensibility](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/mbs/extensibilityGuide/Managed_Build_Extensibility.html?cp=11_0_1) - which covers the details of the APIs
- [What's New in CBS 4.0](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/cdt_build_system/whats_new/4.0/whats_new_CBS_40.html?cp=11_0_3) - is the detailed what's new document when the build system was added. Some slightly dated stuff, but a good overview document.

But the quick start API wise is:

```java
IProject project = ...;
IManagedBuildInfo buildInfo = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(project);
if (buildInfo != null) { // you may also check for C Nature on the project as a precondition
    String buildCommand = buildInfo.getBuildCommand();
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jonah! I had looked at the Managed Build Extensibility before but there is little in the way of actual method signatures for interacting with the build info. For example, even the methods you mentioned aren't documented in the the two guides.

For JDT-based plug-in development, there was rich documentation including Javadocs. Do you know if that exists for CDT plug-in development?

Comment: Beyond what is in those guides and the javadocs of the classes it (and I) have mentioned there is nothing that I know of. The CDT documentation is not as extensive as JDTs, but what you need should be findable in the CDT javadocs. Make sure you have the CDT SDK in your target platform so you get the full javadocs as you are coding in Eclipse.